# jQuery ajax data by form fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am processing a form with jQuery ajax.
I have the following jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'formprocess.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: $('#myForm input[type=\'text\']'),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) { alert('pass'); }
 });
```

And my form is:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="parent[47]child[230][26]" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="parent[47]child[230][27]" value="2" />
  <input type="text" name="parent[28]child[231][29]" value="3" />
  <input type="text" name="parent[28]child[231][31]" value="4" />
</form>
```

And it works fine for form posts over ajax.

On the php side it shows up as:

```
$_POST
: array = 
  parent: array = 
    47: array = 
      child: array = 
        230: array = 
          26: string = "1"
          27: string = "2"
    28: array = 
      child: array = 
        231: array = 
          29: string = "3"
          31: string = "4"
```

But I'd like to split it on the javascript side so that it loops and passes each parent separately. So in this case it would post back twice:

```
$_POST
: array = 
  parent_id = 47
  child: array = 
      230: array = 
        26: string = "1"
        27: string = "2"
```

AND

```
$_POST
: array = 
  parent_id = 28
  child: array = 
       231: array = 
         29: string = "3"
         31: string = "4"
```

So I think I need to use:

```
$('#myForm input[type=\'text\']').each(function(i, tbox) {
    tboxname = tbox.attr('name');
    var myregexp = /parent\[(\d+)\]child\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/;
    var match = myregexp.exec(tboxname);
    var parent_id = match[1];
    var child = 'child['+match[2]+']['+match[3]+']';
}
```

But now I have 2 string values and have lost my object and value.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct - using `.each()` in this case is the right approach, but it'll just let you iterate over each `input` element, and won't really know anything about the "array" inside the `name` attribute for each one.  That seems to be your primary issue here; javascript is just seeing the value of your `name` parameter as a string, and not an array of values.

I wouldn't think of this as a multi-dimensional array in the eyes of js... the each() will just see one big list of elements that you need to invent your own logic to parse through.

Here's what I would try...

```
var parsedData = {};
$('#myForm input[type=\'text\']').each(function(i){
    var thisInput = $(this);
    var thisName = $(this).attr('name');

    // parse your string here, by using conditional statements or maybe by using eval()
    // ... This is where "your own logic" mentioned above would go =)

    parsedData.["someValue"+i] = thisInput.val();
});
```

...And from here you would use the `parsedData` var to pass into your `$.ajax` call.

Hope this helps

Comment: That definitely got me going. I've parsed it apart and got my parent_id variable. But now how do I get the rest of the data to pass back as an array.

Comment: Hmm... maybe you could edit your original question? As for your muli-dimensional `child` array, do you need to actually pass an entire array of data in each one, or do you just need the numbers to get back to php? If it's the former, it would help to know what kind of data you need in your array. If it's the latter, can you just `Regex` (or `String.split()`) the values from your `name` string, and post to php as an object? ie. `{'parent':123,'child':[230,26],'string':3}` ?